# JDBC returns wrong number of affected rows

Tags: mysql, jdbc

If we have a table with 10 rows and we execute this query twice we get the wrong number of affected rows the second time.

```
Statement st = open();

st.executeUpdate("UPDATE  `tickets` SET price=1000"); // return 10
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE  `tickets` SET price=1000"); // return 10
```

Obviously it isn't correct because in first query the price of all rows is updated to 1000 and in the second query nothing actually changes but it returns 10 again!

How can I get the number of rows that are actually updated?

Comment: Technically, databases can (and do) update the row anyway, even though it had the same value already (because it is simpler, or comparing the old and new value might be more expensive than just updating it).

Comment: no if we execute these queries in mysql command line in second query mysql return 0 affected rows

Comment: My comment was intended as an indication that your expectation doesn't apply to all database systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JDBC specification apparently dictates that drivers have `executeUpdate()` return the number of rows *found* by the UPDATE statement, not the number of rows *actually affected*.

To have MySQL Connector/J return the number of rows *actually changed* you can add the property `useAffectedRows=true` to your connection URL, although the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) does warn that it is

> not JDBC-compliant, will break most applications that rely on "found" rows vs. "affected rows" for DML statements

Comment: The JDBC specification (4.2, section 13.1.2.2) says _"the SQL statement being executed returns the number of rows affected by the update for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements"_. However number of rows affected can be different for each database (it might update anyway, even if the value is the same; rows changed by triggers might or might not be included, etc).

Comment: Note this was already so (but differently phrased) in JDBC 1.2, so I'm curious as to what MySQL referenced.