# Out parameter works in MySQL but not in JDBC, always returns same value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This procedure works fine in MySQL, and returns proper value, but when using JDBC it always returns 1.

In MySQL when I call this procedure I will get 1 when the row is updated, and 0 when no.

In JDBC no matter what it always returns 1.

I've tried different JDBC drivers with no result, I also didn't find explanation here why its happening. Ofcourse we could use different code for the same result, but can anyone explain why its happening?

PROCEDURE

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UPDATE_PARTICIPANT`(
IN 
p_id int(11),
p_first_name VARCHAR(45),
OUT
p_suceed INT(11)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE `appdb`.`participants` 
    SET `id`=p_id,
    first_name = p_first_name
    WHERE `id`= p_id;
    SET p_suceed = ROW_COUNT();
END
```

JDBC

```
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn =
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/appdb?" +
                        "user=root&password=password&serverTimezone=UTC");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }

    int id = 3;
    String firstName = "updatedName";

    CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL UPDATE_PARTICIPANT(?,?,?)}");
    cStmt.setInt(1, id);
    cStmt.setString(2, firstName);
    cStmt.registerOutParameter(3,java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    cStmt.execute();
    int outputValue = cStmt.getInt(3);
    System.out.println(outputValue);
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

I've made a short video to better ilustrate problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_WpngvO8o0&feature=youtu.be 
Guys please focus on why variable in MySQL is passed propertly but we can't get it in JDBC :)

EDIT2:

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the
>   number of 
>       rows actually changed. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to 
>       mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is 
>       the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by the WHERE clause.

This could be the cause, by default JDBC driver has this on.

Comment: *Unrelated:* What is the point of ``SET `id`=p_id WHERE `id`=p_id``?

Comment: Even if this isn't what you were asking: You could just do an `executeUpdate()` with a prepared statement of `"UPDATE appdb.participants SET id = ?, first_name = ? WHERE id= ?"` and get the row count as a return value.

Comment: @Andreas it just adds an option for updating id of updated "participant"

Comment: @Mick_Mnemonic thanks, yeah I know, but I simply don't understand why I can't get proper Integer value from out parameter ;(

Comment: @0001 In general, you should never update the ID. Besides, the code *doesn't* "adds an option" for that, since it assign the *same* value, so the ``SET `id`=p_id`` part is meaningless.

Comment: Note from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_row-count) that "For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually changed". Maybe you passed in the same first name value as was already in the table? And I agree with Andreas: don't update the `id` column. Especially, if that's a primary key, you may run into problems with locks escalating to other tables (with foreign keys) etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC returns wrong number of affected rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523589/jdbc-returns-wrong-number-of-affected-rows)

Answer (score 0):

> This could be the cause, by default JDBC driver has [CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS] on.

That is correct. According to the MySQL Connector/J development team's interpretation of the JDBC spec, UPDATE statements should return the number of rows *matched* by the statement, not the number of rows *actually changed*.

If we want the ROW_COUNT() to reflect the number of rows *actually changed* then we need to include the parameter

```
useAffectedRows=true
```

in our JDBC connection URL.